# How can I run a python github project to my nodejs project?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, whisper

So I want to use this python project https://github.com/m-bain/whisperX and access it in my nodejs project.

I am thinking of using https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell but I am not really sure what "py" file to target since this is a github project. I am not a python guy so I am just generally confused on how to include that in my project and access `whisperx` "command" (using https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexecsynccommand-options).

ChatGPT told me to clone the github repo to my repo then access it, but if I do that, I still don't know which 'py' file to target? or do I have to "bundle" it so it's a single py file?

Answer (score 0):

Python projects generally have a `main` file that can be used to run the code.
For the specific repo you linked, this file can be found at `whisperx/__main__.py`. From what I can tell, that should provide you with a CLI, thus exposing the command you are looking for.